# How to removeAtrr from option :not(:contains(' any of this values '))

Tags: jquery

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BtL3f/)

I need remove 'select' from all option without option what contains '+' and '-'

Why not work something like this

```
$('#hidden :not(:contains(+)), #hidden :not(:contains(-))').removeAttr('selected');
```

or

```
$('#hidden :not(:contains(+)):not(:contains(-))').removeAttr('selected');
```

Thanks for any help!

---

This is need me for filter products on site...

product has size and size has colors,

So for example product#1 have size '+9.0' and for this size there is only red and blue colors...

Thanks all for help! everyone +1

Comment: What do you mean by _"remove 'select'"_? Also, you're attempting to target elements with IDs but your elements have classes.

Comment: `.prop('selected', false)`? @j08691 Actually `#hidden` element exists in the fiddle. There is also `.hidden` element :)

Comment: So if the user changes color, you want to deselect+reselect colors but not size?

Comment: the second option works here [http://jsfiddle.net/BtL3f/4/](http://jsfiddle.net/BtL3f/4/) remove selected attr on any element without + or -

Comment: Yes Salman A, and Abraham Uribe your fiddle it's what i need! How i can set your answer is accepted?

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest:

```
$('#hidden, #Size').change(function(){
    $(this).find('option').filter(function(){
        return $(this).text().match(/(\+|-)/);
    }).prop('selected', false);
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/BtL3f/2/).

Note, though, that if those `option`s you're trying to prevent the user selecting are labels, and the following `option` elements represent a group of options, you'd be best off simply relying on HTML's native behaviour, with the `optgroup` tag, for example:

```
<select multiple size="10" id="hidden">
    <option value="">none</option>
    <optgroup label="+9.0">
        <option value="">red</option>
        <option value="">blue</option>
        <option value="">green</option>
    </optgroup>
    <!-- other groups removed for brevity -->
    <optgroup label="-8.8">
        <option value="">red</option>
        <option value="">blue</option>
        <option value="">green</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/BtL3f/5/) (I've amended *only* the `#hidden` `select` element).

References:

- HTML:

  - [`<optgroup>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#edef-OPTGROUP).
- JavaScript:

  - [`String.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match).
- jQuery:

  - [`change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/).
  - [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).
  - [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).
  - [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

Answer (score 1):

Why do want to do that?

If you don't actually want to progress these selections, as they should more stand for a title. Then you could be using the HTML attribute [disabled](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp).

Like:

```
<option disabled = true value="">+9.0</option>
```

I hope this is what you wanted to accomplisch.
**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BtL3f/1/)**

Comment: No not needed disable because this is options i need for filter by products... product has size and size has colors, but for example product#1 have size '+9.0' and for this size there is only red and blue colors...

Answer (score 1):

all you need is quotations around your `:contents()` selector and indicate `option`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#hidden option:not(:contains('+'))").removeAttr('selected');
});
```

see my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AGXV3/)